# Google Maps Api zoom towards marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with some markers and zoom in/out buttons.

When I click on the buttons, I zoom towards/away from the center of the map which is fine when no marker is selected. But if a marker is selected I want to zoom towards/away from that marker when clicking the zoom buttons.

The behavior I want is similar to when zooming using the scroll wheel, where it zooms towards/away from the cursors position, I just want to zoom towards/away from the selected marker.

Is there an easy way to do this with the api or do I need to do my own calculations for this?

EDIT:

After Julien's suggestion, I made the following codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQvZBd

It's a good approach, but not exactly what I was after as it centers the marker directly. I just wanted to zoom towards the marker, not center it. Just like when you use the scroll wheel to zoom towards the pointer.

I found this answer, to a similar question: [Google maps zoom in on marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476321/google-maps-zoom-in-on-marker/38494402#38494402)

Where you calculate the new center yourself:

```
function zoomInAtMarker(marker)
{
    var pos = marker.getPosition();
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
    var span = map.getBounds().toSpan();
    var s = pos.lat() - span.lat() * (pos.lat() - bounds.getSouthWest().lat()) / bounds.toSpan().lat();
    var w = pos.lng() - span.lng() * (pos.lng() - bounds.getSouthWest().lng()) / bounds.toSpan().lng();
    map.panToBounds({ south:s, north:s + span.lat(), west:w, east:w + span.lng()});
}
```

I made a codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddWgaE

This is roughly the functionality I wanted, but I was hoping for a more native way to achieve this.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried? How do you "select" a marker?

Answer (score 0):

You can just work with the ***zoom_changed*** event (ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference).

Little working example that center the zoom on the last clicked marker:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentMarker = null;
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 3,
            center: {lat: -45.363, lng: 131.044}
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            if (currentMarker) {
                map.setCenter({lat: currentMarker.position.lat(), lng: currentMarker.position.lng()});
            }
        });
        var markers = [{
                lat: -33.890542,
                lng: 151.274856
            }, {
                lat: -35.923036,
                lng: 134.259052
            }, {
                lat: -41.028249,
                lng: 177.157507
            }, {
                lat: -66.80010128657071,
                lng: 111.28747820854187
            }, {
                lat: -25.950198,
                lng: 222.259302
            }
        ];
        markers.forEach(m => {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: m.lat, lng: m.lng},
                map: map
            });
            marker.addListener('click', () => {
                currentMarker = marker;
            });
        });
    }
</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @julien, thank you for your suggestion. I made a codepen with it here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQvZBd
It's a good approach, but not exactly what I was after as it centers the marker directly, where I wanted to just zoom towards it.

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476321/google-maps-zoom-in-on-marker/38494402#38494402 which is more what I wanted. I made a codepen with that: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddWgaE

I would prefer a native solution however, but I guess that doesn't exist

Comment: Hi @Nekura, oh I see, well I don't think there is a native solution for what you are looking but the one you came with isn't that bad I think.